# compare jquery selectors performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, jquery-selectors

Looking at improving the performance of my jquery selectors. so any tips or articles as the best per formant jquery selectors? For example selecting the a div's id. Anywhere online I can provide html and compare the different selectors I can use to select the required element.

Answer (score 11):

You can compare selector performance here: http://jsperf.com/

Just setup your HTML, include jQuery and place each selector you want to compare as a test case.

Many of the rules [here](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/) still apply, *however* the game changed a bit in jQuery 1.4.3+, after that Sizzle (jQuery's selector engine) will use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) in browsers that support it.

Comment: Note that Sizzle has used `querySelectorAll()` for quite a while. It was always used for `document` contexts (ie `nodeType == 9`). 1.4.3 introduced using it on element nodes (ie `nodeType == 1`) as well.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://eng.wealthfront.com/2010/10/jquery-right-way.html) goes into some detail about jQuery selectors and their performance. It's mainly about using jQuery the right way. Since a lot of jQuery use revolves around selectors, the article spends some time on them.

Basically a few things to remember:

- If you're looking for performance, use selectors that delegate to native DOM-inspection methods (`getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName`)
- Cache results
- Pseudo-selectors can cause a performance hit.

Comment: One question, by this you mean the use of id on the elements or the use of the getElementById?

Comment: There are certain jQuery selectors that delegate to native DOM-inspection methods. The article goes into detail about that. So if you have a selector that eventually delegates to `getElementById`, then it will perform faster.

Answer (score 0):

One thing these articles don't address is what your starting point is.  If you are starting with the entire DOM tree, then these articles are actually useful.

However, if you have an element to start with, it then depends on what your search is.  Most of my dynamic javascript with MVC templates tends to grab the element on which the action is taken, then do a search for parent objects.  This eliminates the need to uniquely name a container when they are randomly generated-- makes things a lot easier from a dynamic devlopment standpoint.

While searching for a near-parent node may not be as fast as searching for an ID, the performance should be negligible compared to the amount of time and/or performance of generating and tracking a number of unique IDs.

As with everything in development, "it depends" will reign here.

Answer (score 0):

I notice a lot of these type of questions are restricted to performance comparison between different jQuery selectors.
I recently came across an article that compares jQuery selectors against their native Javascript counterparts.

It might sound like a lot of hassle, but the performance gain is quite substantial. More than I imagined actually.

Article:
http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-vs-raw-javascript-1-dom-forms/