# Can jQuery be relied upon?

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a piece of jQuery code that will change the attributes within hundreds of HTML elements.

Can jQuery be relied upon entirely to perform such tasks?

Is there a chance that jQuery code would leave my page inconsistent?

EG.  By not quite completing the task that I expect it to.

Comment: @ZeeTee, why specifically? Because the question concerns if jQuery will repeat something forever? or will it stop after a set # of itterations? :P

Comment: @Coulton, why don't you test this concern on hundreds of elements, and tell us if it breaks...

Comment: @Jakub: I didn't read the description, just the title.

Comment: @jakub I have tried it on my elements and I know that it works as I use it, but I wonder if there are instances where this may not be the case.  And yes, my question is specific to a number of elements, not unlimited elements repeating forever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my sole opinion, I would trust jQuery even in mission critical applications. It's quite stable and never failed me in massive web applications.

You only need to be really careful when you update, as if you are using 3rd Party plugins, they might be not stable or fully compatible with fresh jQuery releases.

Comment: +1 on updating, goes without saying for ANY library/framework, even something as simple as CSS frameworks.

Comment: yeap so true Jakub!
have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will perform the complete task. However, it might get a bit slow since you are talking about hundreds of elements. This might cause the browser to go into some kind of safe mode (telling the user a script is running slow and such).

Therefore, you might want to test how far you can go with it or use a different approach. Maybe some timeout construction where you do it piece by piece.

Comment: internet explorer especially is prone to the above craziness

Comment: Here is a link for "timeout construction", poor man's multithreading: http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

It'll probably complete the task and would trust jQuery to a very high degree. In the end, the performance is also a question of browser speed and [selector speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047977/compare-jquery-selectors-performance). Always check if you use the right selectors.